# Backbone implementation

Tags: django, backbone.js

I have made a Django Application using Python and HTML. And using the Hijax scheme, I have written the server-side logic but now I want the client-side code to be maintained using the Backbone framework for Javascript. I tried searching for several tutorials for designing it using Backbone but I am not clear how to approach it. Please help!

Comment: Please consider adding comments also.

Comment: Maybe try... http://backbonetutorials.com/.  That seems pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at [this project](https://github.com/mpuig/hijax) available on GitHub. Please read also [this article](http://duganchen.ca/single-page-web-app-architecture-done-right/) from Dugan Chen. Both are using **Backbone.js, Django and the Hijax scheme**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was just having look at Dugan Chen's tutorial.